# How to interpret 0.1 unit differences for a predictor variable in a GLM?

Tags: model, statistics, glm, medical

I have been given a assignment with the following question:

"Add waist-hip ratio as an additional predictor variable to your model in 2c) in order to estimate the causal effect of waist-hip ratio on the presence of plaque controlling for potential confounding by age, sex, education and smoking. **Since a unit difference in waist-hip ratio is large any results that you report for waist-hip ratio should relate to 0.1 unit differences.** Assess the fit of the model using any statistical techniques that you judge appropriate, making any modifications to the model if you judge these necessary in order to achieve the aim of the analysis. Interpret your findings."

The dataset provided contains the following variables and factor levels:

```
**Variable Name = Description and coding**

id = Subject identifier

age_cat = Age category (1 = 40-44, 2 = 45-49, 3 = 50-54, 4 = 55-59, 5 = 60-64, 6 = 65-69 years)

sex = Sex (0 = female, 1 = male)

education = Education (0 = Secondary education or less, 1 = University graduate)

smoking = Are you a current smoker? (1 = Never smoked, 2 = No, ex-smoker 3 = Yes, a regular smoker)

**whr = Waist-hip ratio**

plaque = Presence/absence of carotid plaque (0 = absent, 1 = present)

plaque count = Carotid plaque count (only available in a subset)
```

My question relates to the whr variable and I have highlighted the relevant text above in bold. How should I interpret 0.1 unit differences and what should I do to change the whr variable as a result?

Initially, my intuition was to create a new variable by multiplying the waist-hip ratio variable by 10
(whr*10) but a classmate has suggested I divide by 10. Is this true and if so, why?

This is my first time posting a question to stack overflow. I realise I may not have abided by the conventions when constructing this question. Happy to receive any guidance or feedback, just please be constructive.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here; stats.stackexchange.com is more suitable. That said, a question about how the output changes for unit or non-unit changes in predictor variables can be answered without creating new variables -- the question is just, what is p(plaque | whr = nnn + 0.1) compared to p(plaque | whr = nnn), other things being equal.

Comment: Now in general that difference is a function of nnn (i.e. how much it changes depends on where you are in the predictor space), but for many commonly-used models, you can look at the ratio of outputs (or a difference of log probabilities or something), and the comparison turns out to be the slope of a line -- i.e. if you look at the comparison right, it turns out to be the same everywhere, and not a function of location in the predictor space (except being different by which age, sex, education, and smoking stratum you look at).